# Select columns based on string match - dplyr::select

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a data frame ("data") with lots and lots of columns. Some of the columns contain a certain string ("search_string").

How can I use `dplyr::select()` to give me a subset including only the columns that contain the string?

I tried:

```
# columns as boolean vector
select(data, grepl("search_string",colnames(data)))

# columns as vector of column names names 
select(data, colnames(data)[grepl("search_string",colnames(data))])
```

Neither of them work.

I know that `select()` accepts numeric vectors as substitute for columns e.g.:

```
select(data,5,7,9:20)
```

But I don't know how to get a numeric vector of columns `ID`s from my `grepl()` expression.

Comment: See also this SO answer for multiple strings and matches: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29018292/3871924

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Within the **dplyr** world, try:

```
select(iris,contains("Sepal"))
```

See the Selection section in `?select` for numerous other helpers like `starts_with`, `ends_with`, etc.

Comment: Beware that you can come unstuck with this quite easily as by trying to avoid regex, regex comes back to bite you, e.g.: `select(iris, contains(".") )` Not sure how you are supposed to pass `fixed=TRUE` to force searching for an actual `"."`

Comment: @thelatemail That feels like an oversight either in the code or the docs (i.e. are we assuming `fixed = TRUE` or the equivalent). dplyr is still pretty young.

Comment: @thelatemail Oops! So did I!

Comment: Well, that is a rather lame start to my github career then. 'Close as duplicate' coming soon!

Comment: is there a way to do this with a vector of strings?

Comment: @MattBannert see the solution I provided

Comment: inverse also works: eg select(iris, -contains('Sepal')

Answer (score 83):

You can try:

```
select(data, matches("search_string"))
```

It is more general than `contains` - you can use regex (e.g. `"one_string|or_the_other"`).

For more examples, see: http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/dplyr/man/select.html.

Comment: better since supporting regexp

Comment: The link is down now

Comment: conveniently, can also use `!matches(...)`

Answer (score 44):

No need to use `select` just use `[` instead

```
data[,grepl("search_string", colnames(data))]
```

Let's try with `iris` dataset

```
>iris[,grepl("Sepal", colnames(iris))]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1          5.1         3.5
2          4.9         3.0
3          4.7         3.2
4          4.6         3.1
5          5.0         3.6
6          5.4         3.9
```

Comment: @arumbay `dplyr` is a panceum - even when you can do it with `base`, the standard syntax is not as nice/readable/composable - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30153441/907575).

Answer (score 22):

Based on Piotr Migdals response I want to give an alternate solution enabling the possibility for a vector of strings:

```
myVectorOfStrings <- c("foo", "bar")
matchExpression <- paste(myVectorOfStrings, collapse = "|")
# [1] "foo|bar"
df %>% select(matches(matchExpression))
```

Making use of the regex `OR` operator (`|`)

**ATTENTION**: If you really have a plain vector of column names (and do not need the power of RegExpression), please see the comment below this answer (since it's the cleaner solution).

Comment: For a vector of known column names, use `select(df, one_of(array_of_colnames))`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively using a DataFrame of 22 columns:

```
library(plyr) # for baseball dataset.
library(dplyr)

baseball %>% colnames() %>% length()
[1] 22

baseball %>% colnames()
 [1] "id"    "year"  "stint" "team"  "lg"    "g"     "ab"    "r"     "h"     "X2b"   "X3b"   "hr"    "rbi"  
[14] "sb"    "cs"    "bb"    "so"    "ibb"   "hbp"   "sh"    "sf"    "gidp"
```

You can use `starts_with("s")` and `ends_with("b")`:

```
> baseball %>% select(starts_with("s")) %>% head(5)
    stint sb so sh sf
4       1  6  1 NA NA # players.columns.str.startswith('p')
44      1  8  0 NA NA
68      1  2  0 NA NA 
99      1  4  0 NA NA
102     1  3  0 NA NA

> baseball %>% select(ends_with("b")) %>% head(5)
     ab X2b X3b sb bb ibb
4   120  11   3  6  2  NA
44  162   9   4  8  4  NA
68   89   3   1  2  2  NA
99  161   5   1  4  3  NA
102 128   3   7  3  1  NA

# contains("g") matches names that contain “g”.
> baseball %>% select(contains("g")) %>% head(5)
    lg  g gidp
4      25   NA
44     32   NA
68     19   NA
99     33   NA
102    29   NA
```