# select columns based on multiple strings with dplyr contains()

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, matching, multiple-matches

I want to select multiple columns based on their names with a *regex* expression. I am trying to do it with the piping syntax of the `dplyr` package. I checked the other topics, but only found answers about a single string.

With base R:

```
library(dplyr)    
mtcars[grepl('m|ar', names(mtcars))]
###                      mpg am gear carb
### Mazda RX4           21.0  1    4    4
### Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0  1    4    4
```

However it doesn't work with the select/contains way:

```
mtcars %>% select(contains('m|ar'))
### data frame with 0 columns and 32 rows
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use `matches`

```
 mtcars %>%
        select(matches('m|ar')) %>%
        head(2)
 #              mpg am gear carb
 #Mazda RX4      21  1    4    4
 #Mazda RX4 Wag  21  1    4    4
```

According to the `?select` documentation

> ‘matches(x, ignore.case = TRUE)’: selects all variables whose
>             name matches the regular expression ‘x’

Though `contains` work with a single string

```
mtcars %>% 
       select(contains('m'))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, i feel stupid now :-). But one question, still: given that, why should we even use contains(), if matches() does the same and even better?

Comment: @agenis There are several options in `?select` for flexibility of use, I guess.  `contains` take a single string, but when you do this regex type matching, it is better to use `matches`...

Comment: @agenis Because you might want to match "." and not have to think about how to escape it in a regular expression

Comment: Is there a way to not have to pipe the matches, suppose I have a character vector of 30 different matches I am looking for, how can I read that in?

Comment: @MichaelBellhouse  In that case you use `paste` ie. `paste(yourvec, collapse="|")` and use that in `matches`

Comment: akrun, thank you so much.  I;ve been doing a lot of digging and experimenting for this. All the best.

Comment: equivalent_for_filter <- df %>% filter(!grepl(paste(exclude_filter, collapse="|"),variable))

Comment: use `matches('m*.ar')` for "AND" operator

Comment: @titeuf it is a regex code to check either 'm' or 'ar'.  If you want both use the code as stated by OmerAn

Answer (score 21):

You can use `contains` from package `dplyr`, if you give a vector of text options, like this:

```
mtcars %>% 
       select(contains(c("m", "ar"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `contains()` with a vector of as many element as you want works just fine. Actually, `matches()` should be reserved for cases where you need complex matching using REGEX

Answer (score 4):

You could still use [grepl()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep) from base R.

```
df <- mtcars[ , grepl('m|ar', names(mtcars))]
```

...which returns a subset dataframe, `df`, containing columns with `m` or `ar` in the column names

Answer (score 1):

here's an alternative

```
mtcars %>% 
    select(contains('m') | contains('ar')) %>% 
    head(2)

#             mpg am gear carb
# Mazda RX4      21  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag  21  1    4    4
```