# Filtering multiple string columns based on 2 different criteria - questions about "grepl" and "starts_with"

Tags: r, select, filter, dplyr, grepl

I want to create a subset of my data by using the select and filter functions from dplyr. I have consulted a few similar questions about [partial string matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-rows-where-a-column-has-a-string-like-hsa-partial-string-match) and [selecting with grepl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018292/select-columns-based-on-multiple-strings-with-dplyr-contains), but found no solution to my problem.

The columns that I want to filter all start with the same letters, let's say "DGN." So I have DGN1, DGN2, DGN3, etc. all the way up until DGN25. The two criteria I want to filter on are *contains "C18"* and *starts with "153"*.

Ideally, I would want to run a code chunk that looks like this:

```
dgn_subset <- df %>%
    select(ID, date, starts_with("DGN") %>%
    filter(grepl("C18"|starts_with("153"), starts_with("DGN")))
```

There are 2 main issues here --
I don't think that grepl can take "starts_with" as an input for the pattern. Also, it can't take "starts_with" as the column argument (I think it may only be able to filter on one column at a time?).

To get the code to work, I could replace the *starts_with("153")* portion with "153" and the *starts_with("DGN")* portion with "DGN1," but that gives me many observations that I do not want and it only filters on the first DGN column.

Are there any alternative functions or packages I can use to solve my problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Note that `grepl` takes a regular expression but won't work with `starts_with` which is a special dplyr thing. And you can use `across()` with `filter()` to check multiple columns at once.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you very much. Quick question - will `across()` filter for the pattern in every single column or any one column? I forgot to mention that I am just looking for the pattern in any one of the 25 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `filter` with `across`.  where we loop over the columns using `c_across` specifying the column name match in select_helpers (`starts_with`), get a logical output with `grepl` checking for either "C18" or (`|`) the number that starts with (`^`) 153

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
library(stringr)
df %>%
    # // do a row wise grouping
    rowwise() %>%
    # // subset the columns that starts with 'DGN' within c_across
    # // apply grepl condition on the subset
    # // wrap with any for any column in a row meeting the condition
    filter(any(grepl("C18|^153", c_across(starts_with("DGN")))))
```

---

Or with `filter_at`

```
df %>% 
  # //apply the any_vars along with grepl in filter_at
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("DGN")), any_vars(grepl("C18|^153", .)))
```

#### data

```
df <-  data.frame(ID = 1:3, DGN1 = c("2_C18", 32, "1532"), 
          DGN2 = c("24", "C18_2", "23"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I am returned with 0 observations (there should be a couple thousand), so I may just specify all of the combinations that start with "153." What exactly does the "~" do here?

Comment: @emomura Can you update your post with a small example using dput so that I can test it

Comment: @emomura can you check my update.  I tested on a small reprodcuible example

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much. Forgot to mention that I was looking for those criteria in any of the columns, not all - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `startsWith` to select the columns that you want to look for, using `sapply` check for the pattern in those columns. Use `rowSums` to calculate how many times that pattern occurs in each row and then select the row with at-least one occurrence.

```
cols <- startsWith(names(df), 'DGN')
df[rowSums(sapply(df[cols], grepl, pattern = 'C18|^153')) > 0, ]
```

Similar logic but with `lapply` you can do :

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[cols], grepl, pattern = 'C18|^153')), ]
```