# select column names containing string programmatically

Tags: r, select, quote, expr

Given a data frame like:

```
df <- data.frame(z_a = 1:2,
                 z_b = 1:2,
                 y_a = 3:4,
                 y_b = 3:4)
```

I can select columns names that contain a character with:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(contains("a"), contains("b"))

  z_a y_a z_b y_b
1   1   3   1   3
2   2   4   2   4
```

**NOTE** *that the column order has changed. Columns containing `a` come first before columns containing `b`*

I'd like to **select column names that contain characters in a vector** and that reorders the columns.

```
searchfor <- letters[1:2]
```

Using `searchfor`, I'd like to make the following expression and use it in a `select` statement:

```
E <- quote(contains(searchfor[1]), contains(searchfor[2]))
df %>% select_(E)
```

Comment: This is a slightly different question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018292/select-columns-based-on-multiple-strings-with-dplyr.  But It has the same solution.

Comment: Here's a more direct comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923392/select-columns-based-on-string-match-dplyrselect/25923466#25923466

Comment: @wibeasley given the clarification to my original post, the below answers answer my question more closely than the other posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do

```
df %>% 
   select_at(vars(matches(paste(searchfor, collapse="|")))) %>%
   select(order(sub(".*_", "", names(.))))
```

Comment: Not quite the behavior I was looking for. `df %>% select(contains("a"), contains("b"))` changes the order of the columns, which is the output I wanted. I'll make it clear in my post.

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to figure out what you did.

Comment: @ChiPak  In the first `select` I used a regex to extract those column and second remove the substring, order based on that and select the columns. Thanks for your  note

Comment: the second only works if I want alphabetical ordering, is that right? If I wanted arbitrary ordering (determined by order of `searchfor`), it would not work in that case?

Comment: @ChiPak You can add a `factor` with `levels` for a general case

Comment: just wanting to make sure I understand what's going on...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**purrr** solution:

```
library(purrr)
ind_lgl <- map(letters[1:2], ~ grepl(.x, names(df), fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  pmap_lgl(`|`)

df[ind_lgl]
```

With the pipe:

```
df %>%
  `[`(map(letters[1:2], ~ grepl(.x, names(df), fixed = TRUE)) %>%
        pmap_lgl(`|`))
```

If you to get the right order:

```
rank <- map(letters[1:2], ~ grepl(.x, names(df), fixed = TRUE)) %>%
  pmap(c) %>%
  map(which)


ind_chr <- data_frame(colnames = names(df), rank) %>%
  mutate(l = lengths(rank)) %>%
  filter(l > 0) %>%
  mutate(rank = unlist(map(rank, ~ .x[[1]]))) %>%
  arrange(rank) %>%
  pull(colnames)


df[ind_chr]
```

But it is not pretty...

Comment: Not quite the behavior I was looking for. `df %>% select(contains("a"), contains("b"))` changes the order of the columns, which is the output I wanted. Should have made that more clear in my post

Comment: Not pretty...but useful for me to study anyways. You've earned my upvote...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the exact requirement, but is this solution.

```
select(df, matches("a|b"))
```

Comment: Close...two things I wanted. First, use a vector of character elements `searchfor` as arguments to `contains` in `select`. You have not used `searchfor` in your statement. Second, the statements should reorder the columns based on the match, such that the order of `searchfor` should determine the column order of the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Self answer** - here's a solution with `select_` and that still uses `contains` - just in case anyone else is interested:

```
library(iterators)
library(dplyr)
s <- paste0("c(", paste0(sapply(iter(searchfor), function(x) paste0("contains(\"", x, "\")")), collapse=","), ")")
df %>% select_(., s)

  z_a y_a z_b y_b
1   1   3   1   3
2   2   4   2   4
```